# Weird results combining colours

Tags: javascript, algorithm, blur

I'm currently working on a horizontal blur algorithm in javascript, though I doubt the language matters.

I get the data from a canvas which is basically a huge array where every four (RGBA) values stand for one pixel. A value can contain an int ranging from 0 to 255.

When I blur the image, the area's between two different colours turn into strange colours! I've drawn a red rectangle on a black background. Using the algorithm below, I get the following result (4px size):

[image: 4px undesired result]

Though when a use a 1 or 2 pixel size, everything seems to work normally.

[image: 2px desired result]

Please note this is somewhat messy build up. I'm planning to make this all OOP!

```
// s: size
// w: width
// h: height
function blur( s, w, h ) {
    var src = ctx.getImageData( 0, 0, w, h ); // get imagedata from source
    var dst = ctx.createImageData( w, h );    // create imagedata for dest
    var x, y, xo, index, rgb; // predefine vars

    // loop through y axis
    for( y = 0; y < h; y++ ) {
        // loop through x axis
        for( x = 0; x < w; x++ ) {
            rgb = 0; // set total to 0

            // loop through area around current pixel
            for( xo = 0 - s; xo <= s; xo++ ) {
                // get specific index
                index = getIndex( x + xo, y, w );

                // add nothing if the value doesn't exist (borders)
                // if( isNaN( src.data[index] ) ) continue;
                if( typeof src.data[index] === 'undefined' ) continue;

                // add the values to total
                rgb += ( src.data[index] << 16 ) + ( src.data[index + 1] << 8 ) + src.data[index + 2];
            }

            // get the average of all pixels in that area
            rgb = rgb / ( s * 2 + 1);

            // get index of current pixel
            index = getIndex( x, y, w );

            // set pixel in dest
            dst.data[index] = ( rgb & 0xff0000 ) >> 16;    // red
            dst.data[index + 1] = ( rgb & 0x00ff00 ) >> 8; // green
            dst.data[index + 2] = ( rgb & 0x0000ff );      // blue
            dst.data[index + 3] = 255; // alpha
        }
    }

    // add the new image data
    ctx.putImageData( dst, 0, 0 );
}

function getIndex( x, y, w ) {
    // calculate the appropriate index, since every pixel has 4 array values
    return ( y * ( w * 4 ) + ( x * 4 ) );
}
```

So **what is wrong with my algorithm?** I'm a bit lost. Please note that I'm not looking for existing objects/libraries/files for canvas blurring. I like to reinvent everything to educate myself.

---

Edit: I also like to add that the values I get back are truly the values that represent the colours shown on the canvas. That means that's definitely a miscalculation in my algorithm.

Comment: You will also have to provide the code for the `getIndex` function.

Comment: @lanzz I've added the snippet!

Comment: Are you sure about the isNaN ? This looks strange as the data are integers and I'm sure your index would simply go to the next line if you go too far on the right. Testing isNaN on an integer is probably kind of random.

Comment: @dystroy I've changed it to `typeof src.data[index] === 'undefined'` but that still doesn't work unfortunately. Also, if I'm on index 0 and trying to find any array items on the left I'd try to access an array item with an index < 0, so I definitely have to check if that item exists or not.

Comment: If you go to the right, your index is still in the src.data array, but on the next line. You have to explicitly test x+x0 >=0 and <width. (that's a bug but probably not the explanation of your problem).

Comment: I created a relatively fast blur algorithm in Processing, maybe you can adapt it to js: http://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/36882

Comment: First off, I'd add a few more parentheses, to make sure you're not running into issues with operator precedence or associativity, for things like `( s * 2 + 1)` or `( y * ( w * 4 ) + ( x * 4 ) )`. Better safe than sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should average your channels separately. Dividing a packed three-channel value is unlikely to keep each channel within its byte.

Comment: Yes. I was too slow to get to this line but that's the good explanation. Additionally, even computing the mean on the three channels usually gives poor results : it's better to use another color system like HSL.

Answer (score 2):

The average between `0x030000` (dark red) and `0x000000` (black) becomes `0x018000`, which gets a lot of green (0x80)
You should average the channels separately.

Comment: lanzz was too fast! better luck next time ;)